# in a website's reactjs code i can see lot of unused js/css, but how to reverse map it to sourc code files to actually make changes in code?

Tags: reactjs

I have a website which have loading time of 10 sec, and which we want to reduce to 3 second or so. I have two questions on it:

**1.**  When I do an analysis of bundle loading in the network tab of dev tools, I can see some JS/CSS files which have very less usage in home page load. But since bundle.js contains everything, I can't see what JS part of it (which is unused), is present in which source code file. Is there a tool or way to do so, so that I can reverse map (not covered JS and css), to an actual source code file and modify it?

**2.**  While the bundle is downloading, is there a way to show a spinner or progress bar to the user to wait for some more time, which is obviously better than showing blank page?

Tried lighthouse and analysis of loading using network tools

Answer (score 0):

1. React supports code splitting : https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html
2. If you implement code splitting in your app, then you can use a fallback component.

Comment: Thanks for the response. but to code split, first i have to identify what is needed in first load and what isn't, which bring back my original question of how to map non-covered code (from network tab) to source code file, so that i can identify and split it or lazy load it.